# Integrating Django and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

I have an app written in `RAILS' and i want to add few features to the project but i feel like using django to write those features since i am more comfortable in Python/Django.is there any way i can write the app in django and tel Rails server to handle the request to forward the request once django part user is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I have in mind to make this work is for the Django app to provide an API that the Rails app could use. But why would you want to mix the two up? I don't think this is a good idea. Besides using Django only to write certain features is under utilizing it.

Answer (score 1):

If there truly was benefit to introduce an entirely new stack into your environment (personally I question that benefit but you certainly more about your requirements more than I do), I'd go the path of messaging versus a more service driven approach. Going with messaging will better insulate your systems from each other and give you a lot more flexibility which will come in handy as both systems evolve.

Comment: what do you mean by 'messaging' here? Is there specific technology you had in your mind? I'm curious about the possibility of mixing two different web frameworks as well. Because I'm familiar with one, and my partner is familiar with the other.