# Integrate one web framework with another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, playframework, web-frameworks

I'm new to web in general and django (python web framework) as well.

I find python easier to work with but most of my colleagues prefer java.(play framework)

Would it be possible to mix them in a web application?
Would it be easier if I just dump django and start using play?

Someone in [Integrating Django and Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137495/integrating-django-and-rails) mentioned 'messaging', and I wonder what he meant by that.

Comment: By messaging, I believe he simply meant communication over some arbitrary medium - a way for (in your case) Django and Java/Play Framework to communicate. Perhaps a RESTful API? In my experience, establishing effective and efficient communication between two frameworks is more work than it's worth, unless it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely better idea to jump into the Play (or django) then mixing both solutions. Reason is one, fundamental. Although it is possible to mix one framework with other, or even mix frameworks from many languages, first... you need to know all elements at least *very well*. Then you can search for most optimal ways for connecting them and use the best parts from each, to get best possible result.

As de facto Play's and djangos approaches are very similar I see no good reason for trying connecting them, especially, when bigger part of the team uses one solution, the best option is to follow them.

While, as you wrote - you're new to the django as well, that switch should not be a problem. You can just in future write similar project in django and compare productivity, performance etc. Maybe then you'll convince your colleagues for trying something else.

BTW: Messaging between two apps should be done with documented API's, just consider each other as a 'foreign' service. You can share database, but make sure that frameworks don't duplicate functionalities.

In other words - if you'll write a ContenteManager in django, make sure, that Play guys connect to the DB as a client, or vice versa, don't try to mix responsibility between two solutions (even if written in the same language/framework) cause you'll fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think messaging between two separate frameworks is possible by a number of ways :

- intensive exchanging data-files (we're back to DOS days...)
- sharing the same database (not described in books , but I've seen it )
- communicating trough key-value store as a common data-source

All those solutions are the same if you put diesel fuel in your Ferrari .

Anyway , if you step on a framework you don't like , probably it has some kind of database , that you can use . My advice is to abandone the old and ugly framework , instead of learning to work with it - burden in your hands (soundgarden) .